# MainWindow muda de tamanho sozinha quando executo a aplicação

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf, xaml

Saudações!

Criei uma pequena janela em XAML num projeto WPF em que no Design *view* está perfeito, porém quando executo a aplicação em modo Debug a janela muda de tamanho sozinha. O que fazer para que o tamanho da janela não se altere?

Abaixo seguem os prints da tela para facilitar o entendimento.

**Design time**

[image: Design View]

**Debug time**

[image: Runtime View]

**Código XAML**

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="500" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid Margin="0">
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,291,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="409,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="409,291,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Agradeço desde já.

Abraço a todos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver meu problema com ajuda de [alguns camaradas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702108/why-doesnt-visual-studios-designer-match-what-i-see-at-runtime) lá do StackOverflow em Inglês.

Eis o que aprendi!

1. Retirei `Width` e `Height` do elemento `Window` e adicionei `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"`;
2. No elemento `Grid` eu defini `Width="500"` e `Height="350"`.

Pronto, funcionou bem comigo e espero que sirva para mais alguém.

Simples assim!